# Rails: How to touch children records on parent save on accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a call back on my children model that isn't being called:

Book (parent) model:

```
has_many :book_versions, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_versions, reject_if: :all_blank
```

BookVersion (child) model:

```
belongs_to :book
after_save :destroy_self_if_invalid


def destroy_self_if_invalid
  self.destroy if (isbn.blank? || price.blank?)
end
```

I'm trying to make it so that when the user goes to the parent form and clears the nested form fields, the child record deletes itself. However, my callback isn't being fired when I submit the form_for @book, I think because it's saving the children indirectly through the parent without hitting the BookVersion model.

I'm looking for something like `touch: true` but on the `has_many` association, not the `belongs_to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved the callback to `Book` instead of `BookVersion`:

```
after_save :delete_invalid_book_versions

def delete_invalid_book_versions
  book_versions.each do |book_version|
    book_version.destroy if book_version.price.blank?
  end
end
```